# Data encoding - PHP vs C#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, md5

I have something like that written in PHP:

```
$signature = md5($tosigndata);
```

Now, I am trying to replicate this in C#:

```
MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Tools.GetBytes(tosigndata))
```

But that gives me totally different result. How do I need to change my C# code in order to match PHP hash?

PS. Yeah, I know that `.ComputeHash()` returns `byte[]`, but that doesn't change anything, i tried decoding it and it's still a different string.

**Edit**: `Tools.GetBytes()` returns `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tosigndata);`

Comment: you are converting you're string wrong. try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in C#:

```
byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tosigndata); // tosigndata is your string variable
byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
// hashString contains your hash data similar to php md5
```